# How do I make a file public in google cloud storage at the time of writing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I have this snippet of code using `firebase-admin` in nodejs that sometimes fails due to a concurrency issue.

> The metadata for object "" was edited during the operation. Please try again.

```
const file = storage.bucket().file(photoPath);
await file.save(pngData);
await file.makePublic();
```

I expect these to be new files when this code is ran, so my guess on what's happening is that the file gets uploaded and a trigger happens that updates the file. I have no triggers so my guess is it might be something administrative google or firebase is doing.
Ideally, I'd rather just create the file with it public with the same command rather than make a retry.
These files are meant to be consumed on a mobile application and website.

I see that `save` has options that allow for the following, but both create files that don't have public urls.

```
await file.save(pngData, { public: true });
// or
await file.save(pngData, { predefinedAcl: 'publicRead' });
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to handle this?

**Edit**
The following gets thrown occasionally on `file.makePublic()`

````
The metadata for object "<path>" was edited during the operation. Please try again.
    at new ApiError (/Users/gibb-mac/Documents/Projects/abdoc/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/nodejs-common/util.js:79:15)
    at Util.parseHttpRespBody (/Users/gibb-mac/Documents/Projects/abdoc/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/nodejs-common/util.js:214:38)
    at Util.handleResp (/Users/gibb-mac/Documents/Projects/abdoc/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/nodejs-common/util.js:155:117)
    at /Users/gibb-mac/Documents/Projects/abdoc/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/nodejs-common/util.js:535:22
    at onResponse (/Users/gibb-mac/Documents/Projects/abdoc/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:240:7)
    at /Users/gibb-mac/Documents/Projects/abdoc/node_modules/teeny-request/src/index.ts:333:11
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)```
````

Comment: How did you determine there was a concurrency issue?  Which line of code are your certain generates the error (please use some logging or more clear try/catch to know for sure and show the result).

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated the question with logs.

The error message indicates it failed because something else was writing to it at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I realized my data set that I derive what images to use have some duplicates. This error gets thrown whenever I try making the file public again in the same batch.

Sorry about that.